# openssl can't read a .pem file

Tags: openssl, pem, crt

I am basically trying to convert a .crt file into pkcs12 format. However when I try to run the command I always get the error that openssl can't read the .PEM file. I tied everything I could and my PEM structure file is fine. Is there a way to fix this?

Error code:

```
Could not read private key from -inkey file from {filename}.pem
```

command i run:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -inkey {filename}.pem -out {filename}.pkcs12 -in {filename}.crt
```

file structure:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Comment: Please give the content of the input file, saying your pem file structure is fine must be checked since the error code let us suppose it is wrong.

Comment: I have edited my comment and added the file structure

Comment: You don't say which file that is. Your command includes `-inkey {filename}.pem` which means `{filename}.pem` must contain the privatekey; if the data you posted is the contents of `{filename}.pem` it is not a privatekey and cannot be used for `-inkey`. Plus this is not a programming or development issue and is offtopic, but to create a normal PKCS12 you must have both a privatekey and matching certificate; openssl _can_ create a cert-only PKCS12 but not the way you are doing it and the result is mostly not usable for anything.